Create a .zip file which has python scripts and required packages and works inside a python virtual environment inside an air-gapped system
I want to create a python project .zip file to deploy inside a air-gapped system (No internet connection to download dependency packages/modules). Python version inside air-gapped system is python 3.9

.zip should be having all required packages downloaded beofore zipping
it should work inside a python virtual environment inside the air-gapped system.

Please provide me steps to do it.
Thanks in advance
I tried below steps inside gitlab pipeline .yaml file and working. But most of the people are not happy with the workaround. I had to download the python packages after activating python virtual environment inside a gitlab runner and download python packages using pip install. If I do not activate python virtual environment, some of the downloaded packages are missing .so files which was required for my scripts' execution inside the air-gapped python environment. After download, I deactivated the python virtual environment. Then I packaged the downloaded python dependencies along with my script.
Then I have to activate the python virtual environment inside the air-gapped system to depoly the .zip package there.
is there any proper way to do this?

Make the dependencies into a .zip without downloading it? Am I misunderstanding?

Hi @typed-sigterm, Thanks for the reply. We need to download both packages and its dependencies in python virtual environment and need to make it as .zip

You might be looking for something like PyInstaller. See also this relevant, but maybe a bit outdated, question and this incomplete documentation by the Python Packaging Authority.
